# jQuery full screen slideshow in 4 directions

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

Simple question, but answer might be harder. I can't work out the effect on this http://www.socketstudios.com/ site. It's bascialy responsive and full screen presentation. There's scrollTo plugin, which is unavilable anymore, so i'm looking for alternative, cause i'm not sure if it's what causes the effect, and even if is, if you need any more plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the resizing of the images, they are using a script that listens for the `resize` event.

```
$(window).resize(function() {             
var top_target = '#work'+current_section;
var $main = $('#main');
$main.scrollTo(top_target);

var i=0;
    for (i=0;i<=15;i++)
    {
  var $container = $('#work'+i);
  var left_target = '#workcontent1';
  $container.scrollTo(left_target);
    }


var left_target = '#workcontent'+current_image;
var $work_container = $('#work'+current_section);
$work_container.scrollTo(left_target);

// Get Window Size

var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;

myWidth = $(window).width();
myHeight = $(window).height();

if(myHeight >= 900){
    image_height = 900;
    image_width = 1350;
}
else{
    image_height = myHeight;
    image_width = image_height * 1.5;
}

 // Set Image Offset

var $imgcont = $('.imgcontainer');

$imgcont.css('width', +image_width);
    $imgcont.css('margin-top', +image_height / -2 + "px");
$imgcont.css('margin-left', +image_width / -2 + "px");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you could be a ninja and use the cycle plugin and then use scroll up, down, left right, with divs the size of the page and buttons in a fixed position. this requires a jQuery library.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html

very cool idea! :D so a normal scroll up and down with a previous and next on each up and down but as i said you would have to be a ninja for sure.